# Run .NET 4.7 application in same site as .NET 3.5 with global web.config

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, .net-3.5, .net-4.7.2

My company is running a web server with IIS 7. The current setup has multiple .NET 3.5 applications running under the Default Web Site using a global web.config file in the wwwroot folder.

We are in the process of exploring an upgrade to .NET 4.7 for new applications. For this, I am trying to publish a 4.7 application to the Default Web Site. This new 4.7 application has its own web.config file. However, when I try to navigate to this new application I keep receiving this error below which indicates it fails because of the global web.config in the wwwroot folder.

```
 Config Error
    There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined 



Config Source    15:             <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
   16:                 <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
   17:                 <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Is it possible for this 4.7 app to coexist on the same web site as the 3.5 apps with this global web.config? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Not in the same IIS site, all applications in the site (DefaultSite in this case) share the same AppPool and the AppPool can only run 1 version of the framework.

Comment: It is possible, but you should carefully avoid such when you can https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Create a new site with a different Application Pool and use hostheaders to route the requests correctly.